# Ionic 2 beta 11: Initializing datetime component to account for local timezone

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm having trouble with the `datetime` component in Ionic 2 beta 11. From what I gather in the [Ionic API documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/), I should pass in a value from Date.toISOString. This works fine, except the date is displayed as UTC instead of the device's current timezone (PDT for my purposes). For example, the date appears as:

```
09/19/2016 8:46 PM
```

instead of the expected:

```
09/19/2016 1:46 PM
```

Here's my backing class:

```
export class TestPage {
  private _date: Date = new Date();
  public get date(): string {
    return this._date.toISOString();
  }
}
```

Any my template code for TestPage:

```
  <ion-datetime 
      displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A" 
      pickerFormat="MM DD YYYY h mm A" 
      [(ngModel)]="date">
  </ion-datetime>
```

I can work around this by applying the `Date.getTimezoneOffset` to the date value first, but I'd rather avoid this since it seems that the framework should be accounting for timezone in the UI.

```
  public get date(): string {
    let n: number = this._date.getTime();
    n -= (this._date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
    let d: string = new Date(n).toISOString();
    return d;
  }
```

Here's a Plunker I've created to demonstrate the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/2iJRh1zM4pmwcNilWIcG?p=preview

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Like you can see in the docs:

> If datetime values need to be parsed from a certain format, or
>   manipulated (such as adding 5 days to a date, subtracting 30 minutes,
>   etc.), or even formatting data to a specific locale, then **we highly
>   recommend using moment.js to "Parse, validate, manipulate, and display
>   dates in JavaScript"**. Moment.js has quickly become our goto standard
>   when dealing with datetimes within JavaScript, but **Ionic does not
>   prepackage this dependency since most apps will not require it, and
>   its locale configuration should be decided by the end-developer**.

So instead of doing it manually by using `Date.getTimezoneOffset` you could use timezone methods from [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) like this:

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a');
```

or just:

```
var timestamp = 1412144245453; // October 1st, 2014 6:17:25 AM.
moment.tz(timeStamp, 'America/Los_Angeles').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a');  // Output: 09/30/2014 11:17 PM
```

You can check how to import it to the Ionic project [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/faq/).

Answer (score 0):

My scenary odata services,return datetimes as ISO 8601 UTC

```
{ExpectedEndDate:"2016-12-01T04:00:00Z"}
```

I use pipe to show in primeng DataTable

```
<p-column field="ExpectedEndDate" header="F.Prevista">
            <template let-col let-item="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                <span>{{item[col.field] | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
            </template>
</p-column>
```

this show the date in my local time as expected (GMT+0100)

```
01/12/2016 05:00:00
```

Using Ionic DateTime over my model's property, show the edited date as UTC :(
for solve i do this in my form.ts
Declare 2 functions (i presume can be some kind of global)

```
setIonicDateTime(value: string): Date {
    if (value) {
        let date: Date = new Date(value);
        let ionicDate = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds(), date.getUTCMilliseconds());
        return ionicDate;
    }
    return null;
}
getIonicDateTime(value: Date): string {
    if (value) {
        let date: Date = new Date(value);
        let ionicDate = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds()));
        return ionicDate.toISOString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

then wrap my model propery (edit is my model)

```
@Input() set ExpectedEndDate(value: string) {
    this.edit.ExpectedEndDate = this.setIonicDateTime(value);
}
get ExpectedEndDate():string {
   return this.getIonicDateTime(this.edit.ExpectedEndDate);
}
```

in the template the code for for the date use the property instead of model one.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>F.Prevista</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime formControlName="ExpectedEndDate"   displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="ExpectedEndDate">
    </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

This way works fine for me, allways show and edit the dates in local time and store in UTC.
this work allways the dates are ISO 8601 UTC