# Locale time on IONIC2 Datetime picker

Tags: datetime, angular, typescript, ionic2, toisostring

I'm working with IONIC2, Angular2 and Typescript. I have an Datetime working as follows:

> page.html

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
```

> page.ts

```
  date: string = new Date().toISOString();
```

The ion-datetime field shows time with an hour less, how can I display date on Datetime picker considering the timezone?

Comment: Why are you giving a string to that component? Tried without that `.toISOString()` ?

Comment: Yes @mxii, I've tried only with `date: Date = new Date();` but an error occurs: 'ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'month' of null'. I think this happens because ion-datetime try to parse a string with a especific format (ISO) not a Date or another string like `.toString()`, `toUTCString()`, `toLocaleString()`.

Comment: That `ISOString` will return the UTC time without timezone info in it.. I don't know how to tell Ionic to show it using the local-timezone..

Comment: @SamuelFragaMateos please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581875/ionic-2-beta-11-initializing-datetime-component-to-account-for-local-timezone/39600378#39600378). Hope it helps :)

Comment: @sebaferreras that works for me!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581875/ionic-2-beta-11-initializing-datetime-component-to-account-for-local-timezone/39600378#39600378) I solve my problem. Finally I use:

```
moment(new Date().toISOString()).locale('es').format();
```

Thanks to [sebaferreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915438/sebaferreras)

Comment: Sounds great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

the simplest is to remove timezone offset in milliseconds:

```
date = new Date();
myDate: String = new Date(this.date.getTime() - 
                 this.date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000).toISOString();
```